# Show and Edit User Meta in Wordpress using foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the below code to Add custom meta fields and show them in admin user profiles.

````
* Register Custom Fields in User Profiles.
* First we need to set-up which meta fields are important, it was chosen to go for a modular set-up with an array. This way the method is flexible and easy for large number of fields. The key element to the array entry is the meta field name, whereas the value gives a nice printable name.
 */
function mysite_custom_define() {
    $mysite_custom_meta_fields = array();
    $mysite_custom_meta_fields['facebook'] = 'Facebook Profile';
    $mysite_custom_meta_fields['instagram'] = 'Instagram Profile';
    $mysite_custom_meta_fields['twitter'] = 'Twitter Handle';
    return $mysite_custom_meta_fields;
}

/**
 * Register Custom Fields in User Profiles.
 * Create the Columns.
 */
function mysite_columns($defaults) {
    $meta_number = 0;
    $mysite_custom_meta_fields = mysite_custom_define();
    foreach ($mysite_custom_meta_fields as $meta_field_name => $meta_disp_name) {
        $meta_number++;
        $defaults[('mysite-usercolumn-' . $meta_number . '')] = __($meta_disp_name, 'user-column');
    }
    return $defaults;
}

/**
 * Register Custom Fields in User Profiles.
 * Fill the Columns.
 */
function mysite_custom_columns($value, $column_name, $id) {
    $meta_number = 0;
    $mysite_custom_meta_fields = mysite_custom_define();
    foreach ($mysite_custom_meta_fields as $meta_field_name => $meta_disp_name) {
        $meta_number++;
        if( $column_name == ('mysite-usercolumn-' . $meta_number . '') ) {
            return get_the_author_meta($meta_field_name, $id );
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Register Custom Fields in User Profiles.
 * Show the information on the user profile and edit pages.
 */
function mysite_show_extra_profile_fields($user) {
    print('<h2>Social Profiles Information</h2>');

    print('<table class="form-table">');

    $meta_number = 0;
    $mysite_custom_meta_fields = mysite_custom_define();
    foreach ($mysite_custom_meta_fields as $meta_field_name => $meta_disp_name) {
        $meta_number++;
        print('<tr>');
        print('<th><label for="' . $meta_field_name . '">' . $meta_disp_name . '</label></th>');
        print('<td>');
        print('<input type="url" name="' . $meta_field_name . '" id="' . $meta_field_name . '" value="' . esc_attr( get_the_author_meta($meta_field_name, $user->ID ) ) . '" class="regular-text code" /><br />');
        print('<p class="description">Fill in the complete URL of your ' . $meta_disp_name . '</p>');
        print('</td>');
        print('</tr>');
    }
    print('</table>');
}

/**
 * Register Custom Fields in User Profiles.
 * Save Changes.
 */
function mysite_save_extra_profile_fields($user_id) {

    if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id))
        return false;

    $meta_number = 0;
    $mysite_custom_meta_fields = mysite_custom_define();
    foreach ($mysite_custom_meta_fields as $meta_field_name => $meta_disp_name) {
        $meta_number++;
        update_usermeta( $user_id, $meta_field_name, $_POST[$meta_field_name] );
    }
}

/**
 * Register Custom Fields in User Profiles.
 * Integrating the Functions in wordpress.
 */
add_action('show_user_profile', 'mysite_show_extra_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'mysite_show_extra_profile_fields');
add_action('personal_options_update', 'mysite_save_extra_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'mysite_save_extra_profile_fields');
add_action('manage_users_custom_column', 'mysite_custom_columns', 15, 3);
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'mysite_columns', 15, 1); ```
````

What i want now is  display different description for each custom field instead of

````
```<p class="description">Fill in the complete URL of your ' . $meta_disp_name . '</p>```
````

I hope you understand what i am asking for. i want to display a description after each meta field and want to pass the description from the array. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, maybe? (use this instead of the current `mysite_show_extra_profile_fields()` you have)

```
<?php
function mysite_show_extra_profile_fields($user) {
    print('<h2>Social Profiles Information</h2>');

    print('<table class="form-table">');

    $meta_number = 0;
    $mysite_custom_meta_fields = mysite_custom_define();

    // Match keys as defined in mysite_custom_define().
    $custom_meta_fields_desc = array(
        // Format: '{KEY}' => '{DESCRIPTION}',
        'facebook'  => 'Description for Facebook',
        'instagram' => 'Description for Instagram',
        'twitter'   => 'Description for Twitter',
    );

    foreach ($mysite_custom_meta_fields as $meta_field_name => $meta_disp_name) {
        $meta_number++;
        print('<tr>');
        print('<th><label for="' . $meta_field_name . '">' . $meta_disp_name . '</label></th>');
        print('<td>');
        print('<input type="url" name="' . $meta_field_name . '" id="' . $meta_field_name . '" value="' . esc_attr( get_the_author_meta($meta_field_name, $user->ID ) ) . '" class="regular-text code" /><br />');

        $desc = isset( $custom_meta_fields_desc[ $meta_field_name ] ) ?
            $custom_meta_fields_desc[ $meta_field_name ] :         // Use custom description.
            'Fill in the complete URL of your ' . $meta_disp_name; // Use default description.
        print('<p class="description">' . $desc . '</p>');

        print('</td>');
        print('</tr>');
    }
    print('</table>');
}
```